# How to set focus or cursor on TextInput in react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am using `TextInput` component of react native. I want to set focus on it inside onPress function.

```
<TextInput
  ref="messageTextInput"
  style={{
    height: 40,
    width: "100%",
    borderColor: "gray",
    borderWidth: 1,
    marginTop: 8
  }}
  underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
  placeholder={strings.enter_your_message}
  onChangeText={text => this.setState({ text })}
/>

_onPress(navigate) {
  try {
    if (!this.state.text.trim()) {
      Alert.alert(strings.app_name, strings.validate_text);
      this.messageTextInput.focus();
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

It doesn't set focus or cursor on messageTextInput. Does anyone know how to do this in react native ?

Comment: onFocus?: function Callback that is called when the text input is focused., you can search on "Focus" the [documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#selection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please try with:

```
this.refs.messageTextInput.focus();
```

I have used it like this
Example: (removed extra code of TextInput)

```
<TextInput
    onSubmitEditing={() => {
        this.refs.PasswordInput.focus();
    }}
/>
<TextInput
    ref='PasswordInput'
/>
```

Comment: Why not just use TextInput's onFocus event?

Comment: onFocus will be for the same, I have added example to add focus on one input from another. If we need to perform some action while focus on input then we can use onFocus event